# Selected option not displaying when label and select values are the same in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options

Very new to Angular and having a difficult time figuring this one out.

I am using a select to set a variable called units to an option from my list of various measurement units.  Works fine on create, but when I get the saved model back it does not show an active selection from my ng-options.

Example:

```
 select(ng-model="units", ng-options="option.tag as option.name for option in options")

 $scope.options = [
     {name:"lbs", tag:"lbs"},
     {name:"pints", tag:"pint"}
 ]
```

When $scope.units is set to "lbs" nothing shows up in the select field, although on inspection 'lbs' is selected.  However, when $scope.units is set to "pint", pints is displayed and shows as selected.

Does this have something to do with the values of both name and tag being the same?

FYI, getting $scope.options from backend and this was used extensively in previous backbone arch.

Comment: All is working: http://plnkr.co/edit/MvNH41tCJKwpjRYyfvyH

Comment: Depending on your context, you may need to use the `.` (dot) notation on your `units` variable. Something more like `$scope.selected.units` (of course, make sure that `$scope.selected` exists and is a hash